# Linked list changing the node rather than adding another

Tags: c++, linked-list

The program below should in theory create a linked list which the user can then add, display or subtract(not relevant). Currently my issue is trying to get more than one value to print on my linked list.

The main issue I'm pretty sure comes from the function add_node but I can't seem to get it to change at all. (There is a subtract class option, but I omitted the function because it was not relevant.)

What do I need to change to get this to add to the linked list?

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct ToDoList
{
    std::string start_time;
    std::string activity_name;
    int time_for_activity;
    ToDoList *next;
};

void add_node(ToDoList * & head, std::string start, std::string activity,int time )
{
    ToDoList* temp;
    head = new ToDoList;
    temp = new ToDoList;
    head-> start_time = start;
    head-> activity_name = activity;
    head-> time_for_activity = time;
    head-> next = head;
    head = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
    head->next=NULL;
}//in theory this should add another node to the list but it isn't working

int main()
{
    int ans, i = 0;
    std::string start;
    std::string activity;
    int time;
    ToDoList* head;
    ToDoList* a;
    std::cout << "Enter the start time in HH:MM am format: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, start);
    std::cout << "Enter the activity name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, activity);
    std::cout << "Enter the time for the activity: ";
    std::cin >> time;
    //~ add_node(head);
    add_node(head,start,activity,time);

    std::cout << "\nWelcome to the Linked list menu! What would you like to do? \n0 Add a Node \n1 Display the list \n2 Delete a node \n3 Quit \n";
    std::cin >> ans;
    while(ans != 3)//This should print all the values in the list
    {
        std::cin.ignore();
        if(ans == 0)
        {   
            std::cout << "Enter the start time in HH:MM am format: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, start);
            std::cout << "Enter the activity name: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, activity);
            std::cout << "Enter the time for the activity: ";
            std::cin >> time;
            add_node(head,start,activity,time);

        }
        else if( ans == 1 )
        { 
            a = new ToDoList;//creates new pointer for while loop
            a = head;
            while(a != NULL )//loop used for printing
            {
                std::cout << i << " " << a->start_time << " " << a->activity_name << " " << a->time_for_activity << "\n";
                a = a -> next;
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;//resets integer i
        }
        std::cout << "\nWelcome to the Linked list menu! What would you like to do? \n0 Add a Node \n1 Display the list \n2 Delete a node \n3 Quit \n";
        std::cin >> ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So far it only prints the following:

```
Enter the start time in HH:MM am format: 10:00 am
Enter the activity name: Office Hours
Enter the time for the activity: 30

Welcome to the Linked list menu! What would you like to do? 
0 Add a Node 
1 Display the list 
2 Delete a node 
3 Quit 
0
Enter the start time in HH:MM am format: 11:00 am 
Enter the activity name: Lunch
Enter the time for the activity: 60

Welcome to the Linked list menu! What would you like to do? 
0 Add a Node 
1 Display the list 
2 Delete a node 
3 Quit 
1
0   0
test
```

Comment: tutorial [here](http://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo do not need to create a new node at head each time you add a new node. Also, even if you correct just that, you are incorrectly assigning NULL to the next of head every time you add a new node, impeding your access to any member of the list further than the first one. Finally, your assignment of temp->next to temp is another source of problem that would cause you to not be able to access the list element other than the first.

Below is a version of your code with those incorrect statements removed. It seems to work, as you may see [here](http://ideone.com/z5B2jE).

```
void add_node(ToDoList * & head, std::string start, std::string activity,int time )
{
    ToDoList* temp;
    temp = new ToDoList;
    temp-> start_time = start;
    temp-> activity_name = activity;
    temp-> time_for_activity = time;
    temp-> next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

Also, although it wasn't primarily related to your question, as you may see in the version of your code I experimented with on Ideone, I initialized head to NULL, in main, as well as removing an unnecessary dynamic allocation to pointer a. Initializing head is required so that some of your loops can terminate properly (i.e. as opposed to never terminating) while removing the allocation is essential to prevent memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You change `head` at each call of `add_node`:

```
 head = new ToDoList;
```

You may do that only for an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding your head pointer with each call to `add_node`, meaning you lose the list each time. The way you arrange it is also incorrect and should instead be (assuming you add to the head of the list, and not the end)

```
void add_node(ToDoList * & head, std::string start, std::string activity,int time )
{
    ToDoList* temp = new ToDoDoList;
    temp -> start_time = start;
    temp -> activity_name = activity;
    temp -> time_for_activity = time;
    temp -> next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

To make this work, you shouldn't allocate head's pointer in the `main` and instead initialize it to NULL, so that the first call successfully ensures that the end of the list is marked by NULL. I.e.

```
int main()
{
    int ans, i = 0;
    std::string start;
    std::string activity;
    int time;
    ToDoList* head = NULL;
     ....
```

Furthermore, you have a lot of memory leaks in your program. Foremost, you don't ever delete your list, which you will have to do recursively because it's not a double-linked list, i.e. using this function and calling it on `head`

```
void CleanList(ToDoList* node) 
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    CleanList(node->next);
    delete node;
}
```

Furthermore, in `main` you do

```
 a = new ToDoList;//creates new pointer for while loop
 a = head;
```

which is also a memory leak as you instantly loses the reference to the memory just allocated. Instead you should simply say

```
 a = head;
```

**EDIT:**

Fixed typos and have now tested to make sure the code in this answer works and doesn't crash.